# How can I find the least amount of place checks required to determine if a binary number in a range is equal to a specific value?

Tags: optimization, binary

For some G and N, there exists an optimal function/algorithm in the domain [0, G] which can decide if its argument is equal to N by checking the value of only V binary digits. Given G and N, how can I get the smallest possible value of V?

Example:
G = 129, N = 128, the algorithm can be written as:

1. Is the 128s place set? If not, unequal.
2. Is the 1s place set? If so, unequal.
3. Otherwise, equal.

The answer is 2 because 2 places were checked (128s and 1s). Values above 129 are outside the domain of the algorithm and are irrelevant, so they don't need to be checked.

Comment: I don't get this. Do you want to compare integers or doubles ? When you compare two integers in binary format each one having 8 bits I don't see how you achieve this by comparing less than 8 bits.

Comment: @KurtG. Integers in binary format in the range [0, G]. Take for example G = 129, N = 128. If the 128s place is not set on the integer, we know it's less than 128, so they're unequal. Otherwise, if the 1s place is set (along with the 128s place), that means it must be 129 (or possibly greater), so we know they're unequal. Otherwise, they're equal. We don't need to check for example, the 2s place, as that would mean the number is 120 or greater, which is outside the domain of the algorithm. I did the check with only 2 bits there, but that was using intuition. How do I figure out for any G and N?

Comment: 1. Do you agree that $N=128$ can be represented with $8$ bits ? 2. If you have an integer $M\in\{0,...,N+1\}$ and want to check if it equals $N$ then: if one of the bits of $M$ is unequal to the corresponding bit of $N$ they are unequal. 3. Can you think of a situation where you end up comparing all eight bits  of $M$ and $N$ before you are sure that they are equal or not ?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. The point is to figure out most efficient (least amount of bits checked) algorithm for determining equality. For checking equality with 128 and a value in [0, 129], only at most 2 bits are needed as I showed, but I want to figure out that value (2) for an arbitrary N and G 3. Possibly if G was something like 256 and N was 255? How's that relevant?

Comment: Correct, if your $G$ is always $N+1$ and $N$ is a power of $2$ then the binary format of $N$ is $10...0$. If you want to compare a number $M$ from $\{0,...,G\}$ with $N$ you know that if $M$ starts with $0$ it is strictly smaller than $N$. If $M$ starts with $1$ it could be only $N$ or $G=N+1$ which you can distiguish by the last bit.
This method of comparing only two bits works for all $N$ that are a power of $2$ and $G=N+1$ and then for all $M\in\{0,...,G\}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering what the problem is trying to state, it's the following:

Given G and 0 <= N <= G, what is the fewest number of bits you need to check such that if, forall 0 <= x <= G. N = x at those bits, then N = x at all bits?

Example: if G=9 and N=5 then you need to check the 1-place, 2-place and 4-place bits. If G=129 and N=128 then you need to check the 1-place and 128-place bits.

The answer happens to be that only the bits of N where flipping it results in a number that is <= G have to be checked. The proof of that is as follows:

For each bit in N, if flipping that bit in N makes it <= G then we have to check it, because if we do not then N with the bit flipped passes the checks while still being one of the numbers in the set of possibilities. From this follows we have to check each 1-bit from N, since flipping it makes the result <=N which is <=G . If flipping a bit from N makes it > G then we do not have to check it because we already check every 1-bit so if the bit we do not check is flipped the smallest that number could be is N with that bit flipped which is bigger than G and thus isn't in the set of possibilities.